# $\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+} \int_{-1}^1 \frac{f(t)}{t-i\epsilon}dt = \text{PV} \int_{-1}^1 \frac{f(t)}{t} dt + i\pi f(0)$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-principal-value

A textbook I am going through claims that for smooth $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, it holds that

$$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+} \int_{-1}^1 \frac{f(t)}{t-i\epsilon}dt = \text{PV} \int_{-1}^1 \frac{f(t)}{t} dt + i\pi f(0)$$

where PV denotes the Cauchy principal value. I am trying to prove this to myself but I am stuck. Could anyone provide a hint?

Comment: If $f(0)=0$ then $f(t)/t$ is integrable and $f(t)/(t-i\epsilon)$ converges to it in $L^1(-1,1)$, so it is correct. It remains to check what happens when $f$ is constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rewrite the left hand side as
$$
\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int\limits_{-1}^{1}\frac{t+i\epsilon}{t^2+\epsilon^2}f(t)\,dt=f(0)\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int\limits_{-1}^{1}\frac{t+i\epsilon}{t^2+\epsilon^2}\,dt+\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int\limits_{-1}^{1}\frac{t+i\epsilon}{t^2+\epsilon^2}[f(t)-f(0)]\,dt=
$$

$$
=2if(0)\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\arctan\frac{1}{\epsilon}+\int\limits_{-1}^{1}\frac{f(t)-f(0)}{t}\,dt=i\pi f(0)+PV\, \int\limits_{-1}^1\frac{f(t)}{t}\,dt
$$
The reason why $\int\limits_{-1}^{1}\frac{f(t)-f(0)}{t}\,dt$ is the principal value is explained in Mark Viola's comment below.

BTW, this is one of Sokhotski's formulas (1873), related to the existence of the limit
$$
\lim\frac 1{t-i\epsilon}
$$
as $\epsilon\to 0^+$, in the sense of distributions. Namely, the limit is
$$
i\pi\delta+\mathcal{P}\frac 1{x}
$$
where $\mathcal{P}$ is the principal value (as a distribution) and $\delta$ is Dirac's delta.

Comment: $\displaystyle +1$. Nice. It’s usual in Physics.

Comment: Yes. In quantum mechanics.

Comment: @GReyes And electromagnetics

Comment: @GReyes You might want to consider adding the following that defines the principal value integral.  

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^1 \frac{f(t)-f(0)}{t}\,dt&=\lim_{\delta\to0^+}\left(\int_{|t|\le \delta}\frac{f(t)-f(0)}{t}\,dt+\int_{\delta\le |t|\le 1}\frac{f(t)-f(0)}{t}\,dt\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{\delta\to 0^+}\left(O(\delta)+\int_{\delta\le |t|\le 1}\frac{f(t)}{t}\,dt\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{\delta\to 0^+}\int_{\delta\le |t|\le 1}\frac{f(t)}{t}\,dt\\\\
&\equiv \text{PV}\int_{-1}^1 \frac{f(t)}{t}\,dt
\end{align}$$

Comment: @MarkViola You are right. Instead of rewriting everything, I will add a reference to your comment in the answer. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @GReyes You're welcome.  My pleasure.